# How do I split elements in an array of unsigned char

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following:

```
unsigned char input[];
unsigned char *text = &input[];
```

I'm taking in user input as follows:

```
do {
    printf ("Please enter an numeric message terminated by -1:\n");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
}
while (input[0] == '\n')
```

Since my output will give me an array of individual characters, how
can I go about concatenating them. If I enter input such as:

14 156 23 72 122

when I try to work with it, it's breaking it into:

1 4 1 5 6 ...

In other words, when I want to pass it to a function as an unsigned char, 
I want to pass '14', so the function can read the binary of 14, rather than
1, then 4, etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're declaration of `char input[]` and `char *text` are invalid, you need to put a semicolon after your `while` statement, and your loop condition makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands now, your code does not compile.

You cannot declare these variables like this:

```
unsigned char input[]; 
unsigned char *text = &input[];
```

You need to say how big `input` is supposed to be. I'm not sure what you're doing with your second definition.

You also need to put a semicolon after this line

```
while (input[0] == '\n')
```

---

All of that aside, if the input is separated by a know delimiter, you could use `strtok()` instead of reading the string byte by byte.

I scrapped your program because it didn't compile. This is what I assume you're trying to do with your code, adjust accordingly:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * Converts "input" separated by "delims" to an array of "numbers"
 */
size_t str_to_nums(const char* input, const char* delims, int* numbers, size_t numsize)
{
    char* parsed = malloc(strlen(input) + 1); /* allocate memory for a string to tokenize */
    char* tok; /* the current token */
    size_t curr; /* the current index in the numbers array */

    strcpy(parsed, input); /* copy the string so we don't modify the original */

    curr = 0;
    tok = strtok(parsed, delims);

    while(tok != NULL && curr < numsize) { /* tokenize until NULL or we exceed the buffer size */
        numbers[curr++] = atoi(tok); /* convert token to integer */
        tok = strtok(NULL, delims); /* get the next token */
    }

    free(parsed);

    return curr; /* return the number of tokens parsed */
}

int main(void)
{
    char input[256];
    int numbers[64];
    size_t count, i;

    puts("Please enter an numeric message terminated by -1:");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

    count = str_to_nums(input, " ", numbers, sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(*numbers)); /* string is separated by space */

    for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", numbers[i]); /* show the results */
    }
}
```

P.s. This is not concatenation. The phrase your looking for is "string splitting" or "tokenizing".

Comment: Thanks for your added comments and code! I had already fixed up the errors - missed semicolon, and such - but your other notes are much appreciated!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Ah. Good catch. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this!

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
       char *line;
       char *token;
       scanf(" %[^\n]s",line);
       /* get the first token */
       token = strtok(line, " ");

       /* walk through other tokens */
       while( token != NULL ) 
       {
          printf( " %s\n", token );

          token = strtok(NULL, " ");
       }

       return(0);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't allocate any memory for `line`. Also, `scanf` lends itself to buffer overflows and other problems. Using `fgets` was the only thing the OP did right.

Comment: @PCLuddite Oops my bad!